# Вопроизведение случайной музыки?

Tags: c#

Скажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть папка, и как сделать так чтобы нажатии на кнопку, вопроизводилась СЛУЧАЙНЫМ образом выбранная музыка?

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, то в папке лежит набор музыкальных файлов. Вам нужно

1. пронумеровать файлы ([Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.90).aspx)),
2. выбрать случайное число в диапазоне ([Random.Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx)),
3. проиграть файл, соответствующий выбранному числу.

Comment: А как их пронумеровать?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` возвращает массив из названий файлов, к которым можно обратиться по индексу, что непонятного?

Comment: Это понял, но вот как проиграть файл-то... ведь я имею только случайный номер, а название песни, оно строчное + формат.

Comment: гугл по запросу "C# воспроизведение звуков/MP3" выдаёт ноль результатов?

Comment: Используйте случайное число в качестве индекса массива, содержащего названия файлов.